# Extending the SequenceType in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, sequence

I wondered why `map()` and `filter()` in `SequenceType` return both an `Array`.
Actually, I don't think that's necessary. Returning a sequence again feels much more sensible to me.

However, I got stuck when trying to add sequential versions. Here's my attempt with map:

```
extension SequenceType {

   func seqMap<T, S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == T>(
        transform: Self.Generator.Element -> T) -> S 
   {
        var sourceGen = generate()
        let tGen: AnyGenerator<T> = anyGenerator {
            if let el = sourceGen.next() {
                return transform(el)
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        return AnySequence { tGen }
    }
}
```

XCode tells me at the last return statement the following error:

```
cannot invoke initializer for type 'AnySequence<T>' with an argument list of type '(() -> AnyGenerator<T>)'
note: overloads for 'AnySequence<T>' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (S), (() -> G)
```

Actually, my `tGen` is of type `() -> G`, so why does XCode think it is ambiguous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem becomes more apparent if you split the return statement:

```
let tSeq = AnySequence { tGen }
return tSeq // error: cannot convert return expression of type 'AnySequence<T>' to return type 'S'
```

The compiler would infer the placeholder type `S` from the context
of a method call, and that could be any sequence
type with element type `T`, and not necessarily an `AnySequence`.

Here is a simple example demonstrating the same problem:

```
protocol MyProtocol { }
struct MyType { }
extension MyType : MyProtocol { }

func foo<P : Protocol>() -> P {
    return MyType() // error: cannot convert return expression of type 'MyType' to return type 'P'
}
```

To solve the problem, change the return type to `AnySequence<T>`
and drop the generic type `S`:

```
extension SequenceType {

    func seqMap<T>(transform: Self.Generator.Element -> T) -> AnySequence<T>
    {
        var sourceGen = generate()
        let tGen: AnyGenerator<T> = anyGenerator {
            if let el = sourceGen.next() {
                return transform(el)
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        return AnySequence { tGen }
    }
}
```

which can be written more compactly as

```
extension SequenceType {

    func seqMap<T>(transform: Self.Generator.Element -> T) -> AnySequence<T>
    {
        var sourceGen = generate()
        return AnySequence(anyGenerator {
            sourceGen.next().map(transform)
        })
    }
}
```

using the `map()` method of the `Optional` type.

But note that `SequenceType` already has a `lazy` method which returns
a `LazySequenceType`:

```
/// A sequence containing the same elements as a `Base` sequence, but
/// on which some operations such as `map` and `filter` are
/// implemented lazily.
///
/// - See also: `LazySequenceType`
public struct LazySequence<Base : SequenceType>
```

and you can use

```
someSequence.lazy.map { ... }
```

to get a (lazily evaluated) sequence of the mapped values.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. The error message I've got was somewhat misleading. I wasn't aware of the lazy property. Now, this makes sense.